# Meaning of Term Reference in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, terminology

I am learning Drupal. I saw youtube videos which teach Drupal. I frequently hear the word **Term Reference** while learning it.

I google out and searched reference link but could not get clear concept of it.

So can you please briefly explain

> what is the Term Reference and why to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr Read blockquote for basic understanding, rest is examples to clear your thoughts.**

> In drupal, taxonomies(terms and vocabularies) are a [type of
>   entity](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744) like nodes, users. And reference fields are used to refer
>   these entities in another entities.
>
> So, a term reference field will be used to refer a term. So if I place
>   a term reference field in a content type, then I can successfully
>   access terms(related to term reference field) in nodes.
>
> These terms are used to organize contents. Please refer this for more
>   info: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy.

A good example of organizing contents will be in E-Commerce sites. For example: All the products(nodes) can be organized into Shirts, Pants, Shoes etc. using term references(shirt, pant, shoes respectively). And then I can use this field to fetch only shirt products or shoes products.

In vanilla drupal, tags is a reference field used in Article content type. When you create many articles tagging them to some terms like *first*. Then you can fetch all the article with term *first*.